# How to Find a html tag from the repeater in C#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, repeater, findcontrol

I am have td in repeater. i want show and hide it on condition

How to Find a html tag from the repeater in C#?

for find button in repeater we write this code

Button btn=Repeater1.FindControl("Button1") as Button;

but for html a tag?

----- atag=Repeater1.FindControl("id of a tag") as -------;

please fill in the -------

Comment: What code do you have to display us? Generally speaking - you should use FindControl and Controls to find the proper one. But without code it's rather difficult to actually guide you.

Comment: The control must run at server. If it does, use "FindControl" method

Comment: Find the first example of how to use the Repeater control and you'll have your answer. You're asking about the very basics of working with ASP.NET and repeaters. If that doesn't help you, revise your question to be more specific and show what you've tried so far etc.